# What is demeaning data & what is its purpose?

Tags: regression, survey, cross-section

What is demeaning a data?
  When it should be done?  Or what is its use?
Is it necessary to do for a cross section survey data before use for regression analysis?

Comment: Two equivalencies to keep in mind: (1) including a constant in your regression is equivalent to taking out the unconditional mean and (2) including fixed effects for each category $j$ is equivalent taking out the mean conditional on category.